# Redirection of stdout to console and file with verbosity turned on or off

Tags: python, stdout, verbosity

I have written some code just to practice verbosity in python. Verbosity is embedded by means of the `ArgumentParser` module. However, I'd also like to write the `stdout` to file also when verbosity is disabled:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               
import sys

def printable1():
    print "1"

def printable2():
    print "2"

def printable3():
    print "3"

def Main1():
    printable1()
    printable2()

def Main2():
    printable2()
    printable3()

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open("logfile2.log", "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    parser = ArgumentParser(description='PC Test',version="1.0")
    parser.add_argument('--nopc',action='store_true', help='Do not perform test on the PC')
    parser.add_argument('--pc', action='store_true', help='Do perform test on the PC')

    # VERBOSITY 
    parser.add_argument('--vmode', dest='verbose', action='store_true',
                        help='Enable printing of status messages to stdout.')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    sys.stdout = Logger()

    if args.verbose:
        if args.pc:       
            Main1()
        elif args.nopc:
            Main2()
        else:
            Main1()
            Main2()
```

This code writes the stdout to file only when verbosity is enabled with the `--vmode` argument. Can you help me to find a solution?

Comment: I've cleaned up your code to only include relevant lines (removing all the comment-out code, extra whitespace and unused imports); it makes it much easier for us to help you if your samples only contain the code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: thank you Martjin, i'll take care of it in the next future. I apologize again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could use the [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module to handle printing to terminal and writing into a file. The verbosity part is still up to you:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())  # Prints to console.
log.addHandler(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('logfile2.log'))
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # Set logging level here.
```

Since now on, you can use that regular `log` object to perform logging in your script, and the entries will be both sent to console and to the file:

```
log.info('test')
log.warning('test')
```

Also, I recommend using [ConfigDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html) to handle registering loggers and handlers - a more declarative alternative to the way above (you'll still need to instantiate `log` object as above).